# Display rows like a columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to display rows like a column? I need turn this table for each meta_key value.

I have following table:

```
CREATE TABLE wp_postmeta (
  meta_id int  NOT NULL,
  post_id int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  meta_key varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  meta_value varchar(255) 
)
INSERT INTO wp_postmeta ([meta_id], [post_id], [meta_key], [meta_value]) VALUES
(14454, 1614, 'price_bin', '2'),
(14453, 1614, 'price_current', '1'),
(14452, 1614, 'post_tags', ''),
(14451, 1614, 'price_reserve', '3'),
(14450, 1614, 'price_shipping', '4'),
(14449, 1614, 'condition', '1'),
(14448, 1614, 'auction_type', '1'),
(14447, 1614, 'listing_expiry_days', '1'),
(14446, 1614, 'city', '2'),
(14445, 1614, 'listing_price_due', '25'),
(14444, 1614, 'showgooglemap', 'no'),
(14443, 1614, 'topcategory', 'yes'),
(14442, 1614, 'visitorcounter', 'no'),
(14441, 1614, 'html', 'yes'),
(14440, 1614, 'featured', 'no'),
(14439, 1614, 'listing_price', '25'),
(14724, 1658, '_edit_last', '1'),
(14438, 1614, 'listing_expiry_date', ''),
(14437, 1614, 'hits', '0')
```

I'm trying to use the following script:

```
 DECLARE @idList varchar(500),
        @sqlToRun varchar(1000)

SET @idList = STUFF((SELECT (meta_key)
            FROM wp_postmeta
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

SET @sqlToRun ='
SELECT post_id,  ' + @idList + ',
FROM (
    SELECT 
        post_id, meta_key, meta_value
    FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE post_id = 1614
) as s
PIVOT
(
    Max(meta_value)
    FOR [meta_key] IN ('+ @idList +')
)AS pvt'

EXEC (@sqlToRun)
```

[image]

But I getting NULL results. How to fix it?

Output should like this:

```
post_id, price_bin, price_current, price_shipping
1614        2          1            4
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want.  Explain what the problem is with your results.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `meta_key` in `IN` of the `PIVOT` and `meta_value` as content to display  and it will return `NULL` row also, so if you want it not to display then add a condition and rest is fine

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        post_id, meta_key, meta_value
    FROM @wp_postmeta
) as s
PIVOT
(
    Max(meta_value)
    FOR [meta_key] IN ([price_bin], [price_current], [price_shipping], [price_reserve])
)AS pvt
```

**Dynamic** query for `pivoting` to use all `meta_keys` as column header

```
DECLARE @col VARCHAR(2000), @sql VARCHAR(4000)

SELECT @col = COALESCE(@col + ', ','') + QUOTENAME(meta_key)
FROM #wp_postmeta --Store all the columns with comma separated

SET @sql = '
SELECT post_id, ' + @col + '
FROM (
    SELECT 
        post_id, meta_key, meta_value
    FROM #wp_postmeta
) as s
PIVOT
(
    Max(meta_value)
    FOR [meta_key] IN (' + @col + ')
) AS pvt '

--PRINT(@SQL)
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Is it possible to use all meta_keys in IN statement? Like PIVOT
(
    Max(meta_value)
    FOR [meta_key] IN (Select meta_key from wp_postmeta )
)AS pvt

Comment: In that way you can't, you should use dynamic PIVOT for that, google it and try otherwise I will help you.

Comment: I trying to use dynamic PIVOT. But I've error 'The identifier that starts with  is too long. Maximum length is 128.' Can you help me please? I modified query in initial question.

Comment: @KirillRodeonov check my answer once it will helps

Comment: I have updated the dynamic solution above so you can compare with yours and do the necessary changes in your own query.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE #wp_postmeta (
  meta_id int  NOT NULL,
  post_id int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  meta_key varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  meta_value varchar(255) 
)
INSERT INTO #wp_postmeta ([meta_id], [post_id], [meta_key], [meta_value]) VALUES
(14454, 1614, 'price_bin', '2'),
(14453, 1614, 'price_current', '1'),
(14452, 1614, 'post_tags', ''),
(14451, 1614, 'price_reserve', '3'),
(14450, 1614, 'price_shipping', '4'),
(14449, 1614, 'condition', '1'),
(14448, 1614, 'auction_type', '1'),
(14447, 1614, 'listing_expiry_days', '1'),
(14446, 1614, 'city', '2'),
(14445, 1614, 'listing_price_due', '25'),
(14444, 1614, 'showgooglemap', 'no'),
(14443, 1614, 'topcategory', 'yes'),
(14442, 1614, 'visitorcounter', 'no'),
(14441, 1614, 'html', 'yes'),
(14440, 1614, 'featured', 'no'),
(14439, 1614, 'listing_price', '25'),
(14724, 1658, '_edit_last', '1'),
(14438, 1614, 'listing_expiry_date', ''),
(14437, 1614, 'hits', '0')


   DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @cols1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ;

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([meta_key]) 
                from #wp_postmeta

        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')


select @cols1 = STUFF((SELECT ',MAX(' + QUOTENAME([meta_key]) + ') as ' + QUOTENAME([meta_key])
                from #wp_postmeta

        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
    ,1,1,'')




set @query = 'SELECT post_id, ' + (@cols1) + ' from 
            (
                select *
                from #wp_postmeta
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 Max(meta_value)
                for meta_key in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p 
                group by post_id '
--print(@query)
exec(@query)
```

output

```
post_id price_bin   price_current   post_tags   price_reserve   price_shipping  condition   auction_type    listing_expiry_days city    listing_price_due   showgooglemap   topcategory visitorcounter  html    featured    listing_price   _edit_last  listing_expiry_date hits
1614    2   1       3   4   1   1   1   2   25  no  yes no  yes no  25  NULL        0
1658    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1   NULL    NULL
```